# update Typo3 7.6 to 8.7, can't get frontend to work on a local test envirement with XAMPP

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x

I working on updating a Typo3 7.6 to 8.7. I do this on my local machine with XAMPP on windows with PHP 7.2.

I got the backend working. It needed some manual work in the DB, like changing the CType in tt_content for my own content elements as well as filling the colPos.

However when I call the page on the frontend all I get is a timeout:

```
    Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in
 C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3_src-8.7.19\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\MysqliStatement.php on line 92
```

(this does not change if I set `max_execution_time` to 300)

---

Edit: I added an `echo` just before line 92 in the above file, this is the function:

```
public function __construct(\mysqli $conn, $prepareString)
    {
        $this->_conn = $conn;
        echo $prepareString."<br />";
        $this->_stmt = $conn->prepare($prepareString);
        if (false === $this->_stmt) {
            throw new MysqliException($this->_conn->error, $this->_conn->sqlstate, $this->_conn->errno);
        }

        $paramCount = $this->_stmt->param_count;
        if (0 < $paramCount) {
            $this->types = str_repeat('s', $paramCount);
            $this->_bindedValues = array_fill(1, $paramCount, null);
        }
    }
```

What I get is the following statement 1000 of times, always exactly the same:

```
`SELECT `tx_fed_page_controller_action_sub`, `t3ver_oid`, `pid`, `uid` FROM `pages` WHERE (uid = 0) AND ((`pages`.`deleted` = 0) AND (`pages`.`hidden` = 0) AND (`pages`.`starttime` <= 1540305000) AND ((`pages`.`endtime` = 0) OR (`pages`.`endtime` > 1540305000)))`
```

Note: I don't have any entry in pages with uid=0. So I am really not sure what this is good for. Does there need to be a page with uid=0?

---

I enabled logging slow query in mysql, but don't get anything logged with it. I don't get any aditional PHP error nor do I get a log entry in typo3.

So right now I am a bit stuck and don't know how to proceed.

I enabled general logging for mysql and when I call a page on frontent I get this SQL query executed over and over again:

```
SELECT `tx_fed_page_controller_action_sub`, `t3ver_oid`, `pid`, `uid` FROM `pages` WHERE (uid = 0) AND ((`pages`.`deleted` = 0) AND (`pages`.`hidden` = 0) AND (`pages`.`starttime` <= 1540302600) AND ((`pages`.`endtime` = 0) OR (`pages`.`endtime` > 1540302600)))
```

executing this query manually gives back an empty result (I don't have any entry in pages with uid=0). I don't know if that means anything..

What options do I have? How can I find whats missing / where the error is?

Answer (score 0):

**First**: give your PHP more time to run.
in the php.ini configuration increase the max execution time to 240 seconds.
be aware that for TYPO3 in production mode 240 seconds are recommended. If you start the **install-tool** you can do a **system check** and get information about configuration which might need optimization.

**Second**: avoid development mode and use production mode.
the execution is faster, but you will loose the option to debug.

debugging always costs more time and more memory to prepare all that information. maybe 240 seconds are not enough and you even need more memory.

Comment: Oh execution time was `300` before, I set it down so I don't have to wait 5min everytime until I get the error. second: I set everything I could to development mode / enabled logging. I don't need Performance for now, I need infos. 5min (300sec execution time) should be enough to show me the simple landing page even everything gets logged. Is there something else that could hurt me running it in dev-mode?

Comment: nearly everything, especially if you enable all kind of debug information. as edited in my answer: do a check about the system in the install tool. then you may need patience if you have big data and complicated configuration.

Comment: `max_execution_time` is now set to 600, will report back if this change anything

Comment: `max_execution_time` on `600` does not change anything. Also typo3 not create anything in typo3temp other then the folders and the images from the install-tool (test-images).

Comment: I echoed the statement in MysqliStatement.php:92 and I get the same query 1000 times (see also the edit of my question). Any idea what the page uid=0 should be?

Comment: in the table `pages` what info should be in the field `tx_fed_page_controller_action_sub` (the field that is queried 1000times). I checked the pages table and `tx_fed_page_controller_action_sub` is empty in every entry.

Comment: the 'page' with uid is the root page of your page tree. There is no record for this 'page'. and you have records in this 'page' as each record not assigned to an individual page is 'hosted' here (e.g. be-users, languages, ...). But as Daniel said: try to deactivate the extension(s). I also suspect a missing rootpage condition so there is an infinite rootline access. does your output already start with page.uid "0" requests?

Answer (score 0):

The field `tx_fed_page_controller_action_sub` comes from an extension it is not part of the core. Most likely you have flux and fluidpages installed in your system.

Try to deactivate those extensions and proceed without them. Reintegrate them later if you still need them. A timeout often means that there is some kind of recursion going on. From my experience with flux it is possible that a content element has itself set as its own flux_parent and therefore creates an infinite rendering loop that will cause a fatal after the `max_execution_time`.

So, in your case I'd try to find the record that is causing this (seems to be a page record) and/or the code that initiates the Query. You do not need to debug in Doctrine itself :)